# IObservable/IObserver Model in StreamInsight

Tags: c#, system.reactive, streaminsight

Can any one help me out in implementing streamInsight application using  IObservable/IObserver Model. Im not getting the enough source to implement these. Any useful links on these topics in highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @sgtz: Refer these http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee362541.aspx

Comment: thanks.  Was aware of this kind of product, but didn't know MS had an offering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for the basic understanding of observer pattern.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817669.aspx
you might also want to look into Reactive extensions ..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply its really helpful. Hav u used these using StreamInsight.